# Question on example of Gaussian and mean curvature

Tags: differential-geometry

I am lacking a bit of intuition on following question:

> What would be an example of a surface with not everywhere zero gaussian
>   curvature and zero mean curvature, i.e. $K \neq 0$ and $H = 0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A surface with $H=0$ is a [minimal surface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_surface), a surface which locally minimises area. Any minimal surface which isn't the plane will have non-zero Gaussian curvature. Examples include the [catenoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catenoid) and the [helicoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helicoid).